# How can I show all QComboBoxes for each item in a list view?

Tags: c++, qt

I have set up a QItemDelegate that has an editor which is a QComboBox. I have set this item delegate to my list view.

Currently, only when I click on an item in my list view does the combo box show for that particular item. I made it one click by doing this:

```
ui->suggestedListView->setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers );
```

What I want is, for every item in a list view show its combobox instead of making the user double click on it to be able to see it.

Here is my item delegate:

```
#include "include/gui/comboboxdelegate.h"

ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate( QObject *parent )
    : QItemDelegate( parent )
{
}

QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor( QWidget *parent,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem &,
        const QModelIndex & ) const
{
    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox( parent );
    editor->addItem( "Address" );
    editor->addItem( "Address2" );
    editor->addItem( "City" );
    editor->addItem( "Country" );
    editor->addItem( "Date of Birth" );
    editor->addItem( "Email" );
    editor->addItem( "Fax Number" );
    editor->addItem( "First Name" );
    editor->addItem( "Gender" );
    editor->addItem( "Last Activity Timestamp" );
    editor->addItem( "Last Name" );
    editor->addItem( "Middle Name" );
    editor->addItem( "Mobile Number" );
    editor->addItem( "Phone Number" );
    editor->addItem( "Reference Code" );
    editor->addItem( "Signup Category" );
    editor->addItem( "IP Address" );
    editor->addItem( "Signup Timestamp" );
    editor->addItem( "Signup URL" );
    editor->addItem( "State/Province/Region" );
    editor->addItem( "Zip/Postal Code" );
    editor->addItem( "Discard" );

    return editor;
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData( QWidget *editor,
                                      const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    QString value = index.model()->data( index, Qt::EditRole ).toString();

    QComboBox *cBox = static_cast<QComboBox *>( editor );
    cBox->setCurrentIndex( cBox->findText( value ) );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData( QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                     const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    QComboBox *cBox = static_cast<QComboBox *>( editor );
    QString value = cBox->currentText();

    model->setData( index, value, Qt::EditRole );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry( QWidget *editor,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex & ) const
{
    editor->setGeometry( option.rect );
}
```

And here is how I'm setting up my qlist view:

```
ui->suggestedListView->setItemDelegate( new ComboBoxDelegate( ui->suggestedListView ) );
ui->suggestedListView->setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers );
```

Is this even possible? If not, what could be another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw a combobox in your delegate via `QStyle::drawControl`
2. Handle single click in your delegate (`::editorEvent`) in next way: create an editor (`QComboBox`) and force it to show dropdown list.

P.S. use `QStyledItemDelegate` instead of `QItemDelegate`

Comment: This led me in the correct direction. Thank you! I used the exact same functions, except changed QItemDelegate to QStyledItemDelegate and added a paint() function.